# I can't get data with I2C from mpu6050 on STM32F103

Tags: stm32, i2c, mpu6050

I am new I2C communication. I examined some running code. And I used function their used. But I can't get any data. I wonder if I2C have to do initial config? Where is the problem. This is function I wrote:

```c
void GetI2CAccelerometer(uint8_t slaveAddress,uint8_t accelData[6])
{   
    // slaveAddress=0x68 (default address is written in datasheet)  
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1,slaveAddress<<1,1,0x3B,1,200);
    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1,slaveAddress<<1,accelData,6,200);
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1,(slaveAddress<<1)+1,0x3B,1,accelData,1,200);
    // i tried this function too but not working
}
```

I created this project with CubeMX. This is initial I2C config and also GPIO_A clock line is activated in another function which I did not write:

```c
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void) 
{
    hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
    hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
    hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
    hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 208;
    hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
    hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
    hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
    hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
    hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;

    if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your initialization code for the I2C and GPIO? Did you connect the correct pullups for I2C. Is there data going out from the pins or is completely nothing happening?

Comment: i have edited initial I2C code. i have written this code in main function: HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1);  and mpu6050 is connected to stm32 directly. i haven't use any resistor. There is no resistor where i looked. should i connect?

Comment: @Alperen, yes, you have to use PullUp resistors. Usually 3.3K for short lines for 3.3V power is good choice.

Comment: Also, what is `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read` for? This is special function to work with I2C memory chips.

Comment: Try reducing the speed to 88000. The i2c is quirky on STM32s.

Comment: i have tried but still not working

Answer (score 0):

First of all, better use DMA or IT data exchange. Polling is not good, but ok for testing.

You must put pointers to data, not the data itself. The good practice is something like this:

```c
void GetI2CAccelerometer(I2C_HandleTypeDef * hi2c, uint8_t slaveAddress, uint8_t * accelData, size_t size) {
    uint8_t request = 0x3B;

    // slaveAddress=0x68 (default address is written in datasheet)
    // HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint16_t DevAddress, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
    while (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(hi2c, slaveAddress << 1, (uint8_t*)request, 1, 200) != HAL_OK) {
        // Use FreeRTOS vTaskDelay(1) and/or check errors here
        // And check timeout or you will hang over here
    }

    //HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint16_t DevAddress, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
    while (HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(hi2c, slaveAddress << 1, accelData, size, 200) != HAL_OK) {
        // Use FreeRTOS vTaskDelay(1) and/or check errors here
        // And check timeout or you will hang over here
    }

    while (HAL_I2C_GetState(hi2c) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY) {
        // Use FreeRTOS vTaskDelay(1) and/or check errors here
        // And check timeout or you will hang over here
    }
}
```

And then request data by function:

```c
uint8_t accelData[6];

GetI2CAccelerometer(&hi2c1, 0x68, accelData, 6);
```

Thats ok for testing, but bad for production. Get the data and then rewrite to use I2C DMA or IT. Check errors at I2C bus and make some enum to return errors/states from function.

Comment: i ve used 5k pull-up resistors. Vcc is 5v. i ve put them between vcc to sda, vcc to scl. But your code has stuck here :                                             
   if (I2C_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout(hi2c, I2C_FLAG_BUSY, SET, 
  I2C_TIMEOUT_BUSY_FLAG, tickstart) != HAL_OK)
    {
      return HAL_BUSY;
    }

Comment: in HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit() function

Comment: @Alperen, STM32 and 5V power?

Comment: @Alperen, double check the connection. Looks like someone holds the line down. And check device address, it is set by **AD0** Pin. The address may be 0x68 or 0x69.

Comment: i ve just tried 3.3v  and 3.2k and still not working

Comment: AD0 pin is connected to ground

Comment: Check pins connection. And check in documentation if that pins on STM32 are 5V tolerant. Not all pins can hold 5V. And power off/all all devices. HAL_BUSY for long time is SDA line down always. Have a tester? Check the lines.

Comment: maybe sensor is not working properly. i should buy new one

Comment: I would say that you made some wrong connections. Or you did PullDown, not PullUp. If you have oscilloscope or logic analyzer, take a look at the data exchange.

Comment: i have watched scl and sda pin with logic analyzer .when i ran project,i can see just one trigger like ' T ' and there was nothing else

Comment: when i removed and reconnect stm32 power cable 4-5 time,data is coming sometimes maybe there are problem cable connection. i changed mpu6050 position but data didn't change

Comment: You mean, you changed SDA and SCL? Do you connect to correct pins on your STM32? What board do you use? Classic Chinese STM32F103C8 from Ali? Check the pins. Try to move I2C to another pins or use second I2C in CubeMX. How do use the function? How do you call it? In main() cycle or in FreeRTOS task?

Comment: I removed and reconnected stlink usb connection from computer. I don't think the board have a problem. I called function in main as a cycle. I controlled I2C register.The busy bit is always set.